# Error In array :'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' in R

Tags: r, arima

I keep on getting this error : Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

```
month <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
sales <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200)
salesdata <- data.frame(month, sales)
salesdata1 = ts(salesdata[,2])
fit = auto.arima(salesdata1)
pred1 <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 12)
```

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Error in auto.arima(salesdata1) : could not find function "auto.arima"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Will you please help me how to resolve this.  I am new to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First off, you should always *explicitly* include any additional non-base-R packages that you have been using (here `forecast`). This ensures that code is reproducible.**

As to your question, to predict `forecast` ARIMA models you need to use `forecast` instead of `predict`.

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(salesdata1)

pred <- forecast(fit, h = 12)
pred
#   Point Forecast Lo 80 Hi 80 Lo 95 Hi 95
#13           1300  1300  1300  1300  1300
#14           1400  1400  1400  1400  1400
#15           1500  1500  1500  1500  1500
#16           1600  1600  1600  1600  1600
#17           1700  1700  1700  1700  1700
#18           1800  1800  1800  1800  1800
#19           1900  1900  1900  1900  1900
#20           2000  2000  2000  2000  2000
#21           2100  2100  2100  2100  2100
#22           2200  2200  2200  2200  2200
#23           2300  2300  2300  2300  2300
#24           2400  2400  2400  2400  2400

plot(pred)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help. A quick question out all the forecasted columns result which one will be considered as a forecasted one and why?

Comment: @AbhijitKaware In this case, `forecast` gives point estimates (`Point Forecast`) as well as 80% (`Lo 80`, `Hi 80`) and 95% (`Lo 95`, `Hi 95`) confidence intervals. Details are given in `?forecast`.